How to get macOS wallpaper image URL which respects the current color scheme?
I am looking to get the URL of the current wallpaper image on macOS, which also takes the current color scheme into consideration when using wallpapers with a different appearance based on the active color scheme.
To get the URL of the current desktop wallpaper image, I am using the following method:
NSWorkspace.shared.desktopImageURL(for: screen)

This returns the URL correctly, however, it only returns the URL of the light mode variant of the current wallpaper. I would like to get the URL of the variant which matches the currently active color scheme.
Is that possible?

Both variants are stored in the same URL. The HEIC file can store many different images. Try opening the image with Preview.app :)
To get the light and dark images, we need to read the metadata of the HEIC file, which will tell us the respective indices of the light mode image and the dark mode image. Note that there could be other variants of the image, depending on sunrise/sunset times and other factors. I will disregard these in this answer.
Thanks to the reverse engineer here, I have written this function:
func lightDarkImages(url: URL) throws -> (light: CGImage, dark: CGImage) {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else {
        throw Errors.notFound
    }
    guard let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) else {
        throw Errors.noMetadata
    }
    let plistDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    if let solarTag = CGImageMetadataCopyTagWithPath(metadata, nil, "apple_desktop:solar" as CFString),
        let base64String = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(solarTag) as? String,
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
        let indices = try plistDecoder.decode(SolarMetadata.self, from: data)
        return (
            light: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, indices.ap.l, nil)!,
            dark: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, indices.ap.d, nil)!
        )
    } else if let aprTag = CGImageMetadataCopyTagWithPath(metadata, nil, "apple_desktop:apr" as CFString),
              let base64String = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(aprTag) as? String,
              let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
        let indices = try plistDecoder.decode(LightDarkIndex.self, from: data)
        return (
            light: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, indices.l, nil)!,
            dark: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, indices.d, nil)!
        )
    } else {
        throw Errors.invalidMetadata
    }
}

enum Errors: Error {
    case notFound
    case noMetadata
    case invalidMetadata
}

struct LightDarkIndex: Decodable {
    let l: Int
    let d: Int
}

struct SolarMetadata: Decodable {
    let ap: LightDarkIndex
}

Here is a simple SwiftUI view to display them. Set imageFileURL to a HEIC file and see it working.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var light: Image?
    @State var dark: Image?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let light {
                light
            }
            if let dark {
                dark
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
            .onAppear {
                do {
                    let imageFileURL = ...
                    let images = try lightDarkImages(url: imageFileURL)
                    light = Image(nsImage: NSImage(cgImage: images.light, size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))
                    dark = Image(nsImage: NSImage(cgImage: images.dark, size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
}

Here is the result for the "hello Green" wall paper.


Is it possible to get the currently active wallpaper from the set? I realized, like you said, that light and dark color scheme do not determine the color of the wallpaper in all cases.

@Kushagra See the link I included where they discuss what the other information in the apple_desktop:solar key means. The si key (as opposed to the ap key I have extracted here) stores which variant to use depending on the position of the sun. You would need to find the sunset/sunrise times of the current location, and using some math, figure out the position of the sun. Combine that with the info in si to find the correct image. A lot of the code you need is in that link.

Yeah I went through the link. The thing is there's an option to set the still version (dark/light) of a wallpaper which doesn't get affected by the color scheme or time of the day. Doing my own calculations there would return an incorrect wallpaper in this case. That's why I wondered if there's an easier way to get the currently active wallpaper in Sonoma, and not all the variants. Thanks for all the help! Really appreciate it.

@Kushagra Oh you are right! Whether or not the user selected a still version should be stored somewhere on the system too, though it might change in future macOS versions...

Yeah. Previously (before Sonoma), it was in a file called desktoppicture.db as mentioned here but now it seems to have changed. Seems like there's no reliable way of doing this which is future proof.
